# Error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I just download an example from net and when i built that project it gives the following error. I have work 1 complete day just to run that project. so any suggestion

I have checked that file arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 is there at given path but i am unalbe to find cc1 file at location "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/

```
arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: but other application works fine

Answer (score 0):

What was the downloaded example code about? If any file which is included in the bundle is missed, it produces the above error. I got the same error when I worked on a downloaded PDF sample, where the PDF file which was included in the bundle was found missing. So, your problem may be due to the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that application used gestures and that's why it cannot be run on simulator. so  it runs fine on device with Adhoc profile change and entitlements sets.